# Why SQL Server doesn't see database

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2014

I'm implementing full-text search on SQL Server 2014. I've added `dbo.Blocks` table like `dbo.Articles` in the 4th step in this tutorial http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/298/implementing-sql-server-full-text-search-in-an-asp-net-mvc-web-application-with-entity-framework

And I have simplified Search procedure for my purposes:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Search
    @SearchTerm varchar(8000),
    @CurrentPage int = 1, 
    @PageSize int = 20
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @NearPredicate varchar(8000), 
            @AndPredicate varchar(8000), 
            @TotalRecords int

    SELECT 
        @NearPredicate = COALESCE(@NearPredicate + ' NEAR ', '') + items
    FROM 
        dbo.Split(@SearchTerm, ' ') 
    LEFT JOIN 
        sys.fulltext_system_stopwords ON items = stopword
    WHERE 
        stopword IS NULL

    SET @AndPredicate = REPLACE(@NearPredicate, 'NEAR', 'AND')
    SET @NearPredicate = '(' + @NearPredicate + ')'

    SET @TotalRecords  = (
        SELECT 
            COUNT(*) 
        FROM 
            AbstractBuildBlocks 
        WHERE CONTAINS(*, @AndPredicate ) 
        )

    SELECT a.SiteId,
           a.Content,
           ct.Rank,
        @TotalRecords AS TotalRecords
    FROM 
        AbstractBuildBlocks a
            INNER JOIN CONTAINSTABLE (Blocks, *, @NearPredicate ) AS ct ON a.Id = ct.[Key]
    ORDER BY 
        ct.RANK DESC
    OFFSET (@CurrentPage - 1) * @PageSize ROWS FETCH NEXT @PageSize ROWS only

END
```

I try to test this in SQL Server Management Studio: press new query, print `EXEC Search @SearchTerm="sample", @CurrentPage = 1` and hit !Execute.

There are two problems:

1. Small: SQL Server Management Studio underlines `Search` in my query and says:

   > Couldn't find stored procedure 'Search'
2. Big: server when executing query throws an error:

   > Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Procedure Search, Line 34
   >   Invalid object name 'Blocks'.

   on line 34:

   ```
   FROM dbo.Split(@SearchTerm, ' ') /*line 34*/
   ```

I found it strange because I've created database `dbo.Blocks` and in `Split` Function I even don't use this table.

Don't know if it important but `dbo.Split` is underlined with red, message: `Invalid object name`, but despite this procedure has been successfully created and stored.

And the last I've just try to replace `Blocks` with `dbo.Blocks`
here:

```
 FROM 
    AbstractBuildBlocks a
        INNER JOIN CONTAINSTABLE (Blocks, *, @NearPredicate ) AS ct ON a.Id = ct.[Key]
```

and recompile procedure - the error now:

> Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Procedure Search, Line 34
>   Invalid object name 'dbo.Blocks'. /*instead of blocks*/

**UPDATE**  I've used this

```
SELECT '['+SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id)+'].['+name+']'
AS SchemaTable
FROM sys.tables
```

There is no `Blocks` table in result. And this is `Blocks`'s properties
[image]

Comment: 1. Small: the intellisense cache is out of date - press CTRL-SHIFT-R to refresh it

Comment: In your screenshot, `blocks` is not a table. Whats in the tables folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to use the `Blocks` object as a table but it's the name of your full text catalog. If you look at the `CONTAINSTABLE` [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189760.aspx), the first parameter is a table that has been full text indexed. Should that first parameter be `dbo.Search`?

Comment: In the TreeView `Blocks` and `Search` are in the same database. Is it enough to be in the right database?

Comment: Did you try adding the schema name before the table and stored procedure name?

Comment: I try to add `dbo.` but it doesn't help(schema name this is `dbo.`, right?), if I were use IDE for Sql Server I would try to recompile the whole solution, maybe there is similar command in Sql Server Managment Studio?

Comment: I've used: `SELECT '['+SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id)+'].['+name+']'
AS SchemaTable
FROM sys.tables` There is no Blocks tables. What can be wrong?

Comment: Can you expand the tables folder using SQL Server Managent Studio (SSMS)? Does the table show up there? If so, what schema is used? If you can't see it there you've created the table in a different database or there's an issue with permissions. The article you said you followed is using SSMS so that would probably be the quickest tool to find your table versus writing queries.

Comment: Yes, but `Blocks` not in tables folder,but in Storage->Full Text Catalogs folder. Tables and Storage are belong to one database. And in SSMS I can see that tables name in this way: `dbo.TableName`, but `Blocks` have no any schema.

Comment: I've added a screenshot